# The shadow of ImageButton with transparent background

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I have an ImageButton. When I'd added transparent background, the shadow losed. How to fix it without third-party libraries?

```
                <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/player_activity_previous_button"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:tint="@color/color_for_buttons"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_skip_previous_48"
                android:layout_width="64dp"
                android:layout_height="64dp"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/player_activity_play_pause_button"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:stateListAnimator="@null"
                android:elevation="4dp"
                android:translationZ="4dp"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is normal, because a transparent object does not produce a shadow ;)

However, changing the background of an `ImageButton`, will also change the background behaviour.

If you want to change only the colour, then, use this

```
<ImageButton
    ...
    app:backgroundTint="@color/transparent"
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of cardView and imageView instead of the imageButton with transparent background, first but add a dependency in gradle file.

```
dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.0.1'
-------
```

}

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
app:cardElevation="8dp"
card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/white">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/dish_image"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true" />
```

to increase the shadow effect just increase the card elevation

Answer (score -1):

You can use 9 patch image as the background for shadow.